# How can i filter the data in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter

I used pagination to my view and can search data with subject_name keywords but now i want search them according to their subject duration in dropdown format.

views.py

```
def servicesview(request):
    key = request.GET.get("search_key", "")
    inst = request.GET.get("search_key1", "")
    q_objects = Q()
    if key:
        q_objects.add(Q(subject_name__icontains=key), Q.AND)
    if inst:
        q_objects.add(Q(subject_duration=inst), Q.AND)
    if q_objects:
        services = ServicesData.objects.filter(q_objects)
    else:
        services = ServicesData.objects.all()
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(services, 2)
    try:
        services = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        services = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        services = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'services.html',
               {'services': services, 'key': key,'inst':inst})
```

services.html

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="search_key" value="{{key}}" 
    placeholder="Search..">
    <select>
        <option name="search_key1" value="{{inst}}">Select your 
    option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

But i am not getting the data in subject duration:

[image]

Please someone help

Comment: Check once answer is updated please add your database field in q_objects.add(Q(yourdatabasefield=search_key1), Q.AND)

Comment: It will never render....First have to get the model field in views and after assigning a key to the field have to put in .html......I am not getting the desired thing sir...After doing this after searching the pagination is not working...

Comment: After filtering is total data is greater then 2 or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

q_objects will collect all filter data and pass to queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def servicesview(request):
    key = request.GET.get("search_key", "")
    search_key1 = request.GET.get("search_key1", "")
    q_objects = Q()
    if key:
        q_objects.add(Q(subject_name__icontains=key), Q.AND)
    if search_key1:
        q_objects.add(Q(search_key1=search_key1), Q.AND)
    if q_objects:
        services = ServicesData.objects.filter(q_objects)
    else:
        services = ServicesData.objects.all()
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
        paginator = Paginator(services, 2)
        try:
            services = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            services = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            services = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'services.html',
                   {'services': services, 'key': key})
```

Comment: Can you please check once...I updated the picture. See there i am not getting the data from my model. I want filter according to my subject durations available.

Comment: Do yo want to filter with only keywords and select options?

Comment: That search box i had given for subject_name and it will search if i trype any subject name there. I want durations in that dropdown menu so that user will put subject name in searchbox and select time available from that dropdown menu.

Comment: That means you want to search only 2 field subject_name and subject_duration? Is it true. Then i will edit answer.

Comment: As you said i edited answer please let me know is it works or not. Change your duration field as database field.

Comment: Sir please check once i updated the question...The data for duration i am not getting there in that drop down

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating your  accordingly. You need to loop over the possible options in your html, e.g.

```
<select>
    <option name="search_key1" value="">Make you choice</option>
    {% for service in services %}
    <option name="search_key1" value="{{ service.subject_duration }}">{{ service.subject_duraion }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

However, as I can imagine that there can be multiple services with an identical service_durations I would recommend explicitly creating a queryset of distinct service_durations in your view and then passing it to your template, e.g. in your view:

```
service_durations = Service.objects.order_by('service_duration*).values('service_duration').distinct()
```

then add this to the context of your render and loop over it as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should like this

```
def servicesview(request):
    keyword = Db.objects.all().values_list('keyword', flat=True)
    sub = request.GET.get("search_key", "")
    q_objects = Q()
    if sub:
        q_objects.add(Q(subject_name__icontains=sub), Q.AND)
    if q_objects:
        services = ServicesData.objects.filter(q_objects)
    else:
        services = ServicesData.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(services, 2)
    try:
        services = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        services = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        services = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'services.html',
              {'services': services, 'sub': sub, 'keyword':keyword})
```